# Nested table which inherits its namespace cannot have multiple parent tables in different namespaces

Tags: c#, xml

I am using dataset.readxml to populate dataset from xml as below.

```csharp
ds.ReadXml("C:\\Data\\mytestdesigndata.xml");
```

However I get an exception which says:

> Nested table 'BRANCH' which inherits its namespace cannot have multiple parent tables in different namespaces

The xml data is as below

```xml
<ASchema>
  <A:Data DBREF="=24140/157" xmlns:A="http://www.test.com/xml/a">
   <B:BRANCH DBREF="=24140/158">
  </B:BRANCH>
  </A:Data>
  <A:TEST DBREF="=24174/138" xmlns:A="http://www.test.com/xml/a">
   <B:BRANCH DBREF="=24174/139" >
   </B:BRANCH>
  </A:TEST>
</ASchema>
```

I understand that issue is with `B:BRANCH` mapped to both `A:Data` and `A:TEST`.

I have no control over the data. How can I solve the issue and still get the dataset in my C# application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below removes all namesapces from the XML using Regex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"(</?)(\w+:)";

            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1");

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(output);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thats a topclass solution and it definitely worked. Thanks for that. i have a doubt though , will making the namespace changes cause data to come differently ?

Comment: Not with the sample data you provided.

Comment: @jdweng i have same issue for this post and i don't understand how i implement ur solution to my code.